# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar el body dentro de un iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

¿Cómo haría para seleccionar el body dentro de un iframe, el cual no tiene id ni clase? ¿Sería así:

```
$("iframe")
```

Comment: Puedes probar con `$('iframe').contents().find('body')`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
$("iframe>body")
```

o

```
$("iframe body")
```

Comment: Gracias, usé $("iframe").contents().find("body") y funcionó también

Comment: Si, es lo mismo, pero mas eficiente es usarlo de esta manera $("iframe>body")  ya que si hay otro body dentro del iframe, te podria dar un error.